# How can I filter the data of foreach?

Tags: laravel

I have this design:

[image]

I need to say: last post that I add it put it in the head of design then other put them down.

My shut :) Html and foreach code:

```
@if ($user->projects->count() > 0)
<section class="latest section shadow-sm">
    <h1>Projects</h1>
    <div class="section-inner">
        @foreach ($user->projects->sortByDesc('id')->take(1) as $project)
            <div class="item featured text-center ">
                // head post
            </div>
        @endforeach

        @foreach ($projects_last->sortByDesc('id') as $project)
            <div class="item row">    
                // other  post
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div><!--//section-inner-->                
</section><!--//section-->
@endif
```

Code of controller for `$projects_last`:

```
$projects_last = $user->projects;
$projects_last->pop();

return view('frontend.user_profile',compact('user','projects_last'));
```

I have the problem with when I say if the `@if ($user->projects->count() > 0)` do not show any thing but still show me the `<h1>Projects</h1>` even it is empty!

And if you have any suggest to making my code better pls do it with thankful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate `Collections` you have to get them. So you have to use `get()` to get the results.

```
...
@foreach ($user->projects->sortByDesc('id')->take(1)->get() as $project)
...
```

and

```
...
@foreach ($projects_last->sortByDesc('id')->get() as $project)
...
```

You can see here the documentation: [Laravel query documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

**Note**: if you want to get just one element in your first `foreach` loop you can use `first()` instead of `take(1)`. You code will be like that:

```
@php($first_project = $user->projects->sortByDesc('id')->first())
@if (!is_null($first_project))
// Use $first_project as $project variable 
@enif
```

Comment: got error with your code: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in this line @php($first_project = $user->projects->sortByDesc('id')->first())

Comment: And still get the <h1>Projects</h1> even the data is empty in first @if

Comment: If you use `first()` you can not use the `@foreach` statement. `first()` return object (that it is not iterable), `get()` return an array. If you see "Project" title it means that the counter is more than 0.

Comment: What appends if you use `get()` as my first example?

Comment: this error show when I use get  ( Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in )

Comment: And if you use `orderBy('id', 'DESC')` instead of `sortByDesc('id')`?

Comment: Now everything is cool, but still stay one thing which is when the whole foreach is empty I need to say do not show the whole section if the ( $user->project ) is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205032/discussion-between-stefano-and-ahmed).